# Can't remove table borders

Tags: html, css

Hey dear people of stack,

I tried to remove the borders of my table but it didn't work. In the attached code you see that it is all done inline, this is because this is a wordpress php file where I want the css in the rest of the page to remain the way it was.

So basically I need to get rid of the bar in the middle.
Thanks in advance

[image]

```html
<div class="row" style="background-color:#e6e6e6; padding: 50px;">
<table style="border: none; border-collapse:collapse; border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;">
<tbody style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;">
<tr style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;">
 <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;"> <center><img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_alarm_black_24dp_2x.png"></center></td>
 <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;"> <center><img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_reply_black_24dp_2x.png"></center></td>
 <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;"> <center><img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_attach_money_black_24dp_2x.png"></center></td>
 <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;"> <center><img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_settings_black_24dp_2x.png"</center></td>
 <td style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;"> <center><img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_airplanemode_active_black_24dp_2x.png"></center></td>
</tr>
<tr style="border-top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;">
 <td> <center><h5>Livrare 24-48 ore</h3></center></td>
 <td> <center><h5>Retur produse 14 zile</h5></center></td>
 <td> <center><h5>plata ramburs</center></h5></td>
 <td> <center><h5>garantia Makeblock</center></h5></td>
 <td> <center><h5>transport gratuit peste 990 lei</h5></center></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's already removed in your example?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Stop using the `<center>` element. It no longer exists. also don't use tables for layout; used tables for tabular data. Use CSS for layout.

Comment: note: you didn't close the fourth image tag with a ">" bracket

Comment: have you tried to include "border-bottom-style: none" on the upper td cells like you di it with the "border-top-style" ?

Comment: @j08691 I agree. Posted an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an alternative (if you want to avoid the `table` markup).

```css
.icon-block {
  display: flex;
}

.icon-block span {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-block">
  <span>
  <img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_alarm_black_24dp_2x.png"/>
  <p>Livrare 24-48 ore</p>
  </span>

  <span>
  <img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_reply_black_24dp_2x.png"/>
  <p>Retur produse 14 zile</p>
  </span>

  <span>
  <img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_attach_money_black_24dp_2x.png"/>
  <p>plata ramburs</p>
  </span>

  <span>
  <img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_settings_black_24dp_2x.png"/>
  <p>garantia Makeblock</p>
  </span>
  
  <span>
  <img src="http://makeblockshop.ro/wp-content/uploads/IconsUpload/ic_airplanemode_active_black_24dp_2x.png"/>
  <p>transport gratuit peste 990 lei</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="0" style="border: none; border-collapse:collapse; border-   top-width: 0px; border-top-style: none;">
<tbody>
```

If browser capability issue then also add border="0"

Answer (score 0):

td is the reason of that border on your site produc pages. If you have any custom css file on your site then add this

```
.woocommerce div.product table tr td{
  border:none;
}
```